# Should TypeScript's mapped types have a value for every key?

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

I am wondering whether every key in a mapped type should have a defined value.

I would not expect this to be the case as it would require indefeasibly many values. However, then I'd expect `Partial<T>` to be assignable to a mapped type `T`, which it is not. Additionally, when reading a value from a mapped type, no `typeof value === 'undefined'` check is necessary.

```js
type Mapped = { [key: string]: string };

// This works, so not all keys have to be defined
const mapped: Mapped = { 'a': 'b' };

// This is valid even with strict checks even though 's' is undefined
const s: string = mapped['c'];

const partialMapped: Partial<Mapped> = mapped;
// This doesn't work because `Partial<Mapped>` is of type `{ [key: string]: string | undefined }`
const secondMapped: Mapped = partialMapped;
```

Since `{ 'a': 'b' }` is assignable to a `Mapped` variable, I would expect `Partial<Mapped>` to be assignable to `Mapped` as well, but is is not. Is this because the value `undefined` is not the same as the absence of a key? Is there a variant on `Partial` that makes keys optional instead?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works with strict null checks off, because you can then assign `undefined` values to a `string`. We're talking about *values* here, the keys are indifferent!

Your index type signature for `Mapped` promises no particular keys, so assigning a type with zero or more keys will work. What isn't allowed is the assignment of non-string values (like `undefined` and `null`) and this is what the error is highlighting.

Here is a contrived example of what the error is guarding against:

```
var undef: undefined;
const partialMapped: Partial<Mapped> = {a: undef, b: undef}; // Works
```

The partial version can accept undefined values. The "full" version wouldn't allow this.

```
var undef: undefined;
const mapped: Mapped = {a: undef, b: undef}; // Warnings!
```